# Understanding pointers and references in C++

Tags: c++

Would someone explain the below code?

```
A{}

C{public: begin(&a); private: A *a;}

begin(&a)
{
   a = &a;
}

B{private: A *a; C *c; start(); }

start(){
   c->begin(&a);
}
```

=> In B, the object A is created and in C the object A is referenced to the object a in B.

then I got this problem:

> no matching function for call to: begin(a**), candidate: begin(&a)

Otherwise, I can write this in C# and I am not sure how to implement this in C++:

```
public class A
{
   public A(){}
}

public class B
{
   A a;
   C c;
   public B()
   {
      c = new C();
   } 

   void start()
   {
       a = new A();
       c.begin(a);
   }
}

public class C
{
    A a;
    public C(){}

    public void begin(A a)
    {
      this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post *real* code, this is confusing.

Comment: I'm more than half tempted to remove the C++ tag.

Comment: The error message seems like an error message spit out by a C++ compiler. Obviously the syntax is way way off.

Comment: Hi, I thought it is clear: what I want is quite simple in Java or C# but this is the first time I am working in a C++ project and pointers give me really very headache. I have 3 classes A, B and C. The class C creates objects A and C. The class B has a declaration of class A and the object A in C is referenced to the object A in B. because the object A needs to be updated so in the class A i have method start to update the object A for the class B. I hope it is clear! thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question by providing equivalent C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to get the syntax correct?

```
class A
{};

class B
{
   std::auto_ptr<A> a;  // This object owns A so use a smart pointer to indicate ownership.
   C                c;

   B(B const&);           // Disable copying. If you want copying use boost::shared_ptr
   B& operator=(B const&);// Disable copying.

   public:   
     void start()
     {
       a.reset(new A());
       c.begin(a.get());
     }
};

class C
{
    A* a;
    public:
      C()
       : a(NULL)
      {}

    void begin(A* pA)
    {
      a = pA;
    }
};
```

Comment: I hope your example wasn't an attempt to fix it.

Comment: Just an attempt to decipher the above. The OP obviously understands the concepts of OO (at a basic level) but has no grasp of C++ syntax.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reformatting. But I would like to pass the reference by calling the methods instead of constructing the class.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question by providing equivalent C# code.

Comment: @JoesyXHN: Updated the C++ to match your C#.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the address of a and receiving the object a by reference... that's not what you want. You want to pass the real object, but receive it by reference. If a is a pointer, then you're passing the address of the pointer (hence the **). Dereference it and pass the actual object

Comment: but then I got this problem: error: expected ';' before ')' token :(

Answer (score 1):

The compiler complains about the type of the object you pass to the function C::begin().

As far as I can see, you declare your function as a function taking a reference as parameter.

So, the call should be `c->begin(*a)` not `c->begin(&a)`.

Comment: Yes, it is not complaining about: expected ';' before ')'

Comment: If there is a syntax error, you should post your whole code for us to be able to see that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the way C++ references work. If you want to pass a reference to a method, you don't need to do anything at the call site—there's no need to use the address of operator (&) like there is with a pointer. See, for example, this simple C++ program that uses references:

```
#include <iostream>

void test (int& a) {
    a = 7;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    int q;
    test (q);
    std::cout << q << std::endl;
}
```

The reference is passed without any special decorations. If you want to assign it to a pointer, you do need to use the address of operator to get a pointer from a reference, like so:

```
#include <iostream>

int* ptr;

void test (int& a) {
    a = 7;
    ptr = &a;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    int q;
    test (q);
    std::cout << q << std::endl;
    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
}
```

In your example, the definition of `begin (&a)` is correct, but its call site in `start` is incorrect, and should be written as `c->begin (*a)` (you can't pass a pointer to a method expecting a reference, so you need to dereference a first).

Comment: Hi, Thanks. It is clear but then I got this problem: error: expected ';' before ')' token :(